# How to Control radio IPTV on set-top-box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iptv

I develop module radio for set-top-box in php,html5 and javascript .
 I dont know what script to control radio:sound,radioprogress and radio info.
 In other module TV or VOD they call function

```
function play(id,type){
    window.p2pobjet.play(id,'123.30.104.83:8001',type);
}
```

I dont know how to do radio player for set top box
 Any one help me.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any API document for that?

Comment: what do mean about radio player? some of stb have a embeded palyer that you can use that palyer for play any content you are, for some of stb you must use video tag in your page that will load in stb